# Copying data from S3 to AWS redshift using python and psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2, amazon-redshift

I'm having issues executing the copy command to load data from S3 to Amazon's Redshift from python.
I have the following copy command:

```
copy moves from 's3://<my_bucket_name>/moves_data/2013-03-24/18/moves'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<key_id>;aws_secret_access_key=<key_secret>'
removequotes
delimiter ',';
```

When I execute this command using SQL Workbench/j everything works as expected, however when I try to execute this with python and psycopg2 the command pass OK but no data is loaded and no error is thrown.
tried the following two options (assume psycopg2 connection is OK because it is):

```
cursor.execute(copy_command)  
cursor.copy_expert(copy_command, sys.stdout)
```

both pass with no warning yet data isn't loaded

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You need to call commit() after execute() otherwise it won't be effective.

Comment: related note: best practice when using "load data from S3 to Redshift" is to verify the operation in the stl_load_commits table. More info in the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/verifying-that-data-loaded-correctly.html)

Answer (score 29):

I have used this exact setup (psycopg2 + redshift + COPY) successfully. Did you commit afterwards? SQL Workbench defaults to auto-commit while psycopg2 defaults to opening a transaction, so the data won't be visible until you call commit() on your connection.

The full workflow is:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("COPY...")
conn.commit()
```

I don't believe that copy_expert() or  any of the cursor.copy_* commands work with Redshift.

Comment: this solved the problem for me.  I was trying to use my sqlalchemy framework to run the copy command and I couldn't get the load to commit.  related thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271049/redshift-copy-operation-doesnt-work-in-sqlalchemy

unfortunately the auto commit solution with sqlalchemy explained there didn't work for me, but the above with psycopg2 did

Comment: @Voket it get's stucked on execute for me and then cannot run the conn.commit().  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18):

First, make sure the transaction is *committed*.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(copy_cmd_str)
conn.commit()
```

you can ensure a transaction-commit with following way as well (ensuring releasing the resources),

```
with psycopg2.connect(conn_string) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute(copy_cmd_str)
```

When a connection exits the with block, if no exception has been raised by the block, the transaction is *committed*. In case of exception the transaction is rolled back.

Secondly, even doing *commit* does not help when the data to be loaded takes some long time and exceeds connect_timeout (and can't commit). So when explicit commit doesn't help, try with an increased timeout.

Comment: Thanks @str, I was struggling with this and completely forgot to check the commit!

Answer (score 5):

if you are using sqlalchemy, copy command will not auto commit by itself. this worked for me:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
eng = create_engine(...)
command = """
copy command here
"""
conn = eng.connect()
result = conn.execution_options(autocommit=True).execute(command)
result.close()
```

Answer (score -8):

The syntax should be similar to DDL statements

```
# Create table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
             (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')
```