# Redshift COPY operation doesn't work in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to do a Redshift COPY in SQLAlchemy.

The following SQL correctly copies objects from my S3 bucket into my Redshift table when I execute it in psql:

```
COPY posts FROM 's3://mybucket/the/key/prefix' 
WITH CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=myaccesskey;aws_secret_access_key=mysecretaccesskey' 
JSON AS 'auto';
```

I have several files named

```
s3://mybucket/the/key/prefix.001.json
s3://mybucket/the/key/prefix.002.json   
etc.
```

I can verify that the new rows were added to the table with `select count(*) from posts`.

However, when I execute the exact same SQL expression in SQLAlchemy, execute completes without error, but no rows get added to my table.

```
session = get_redshift_session()
session.bind.execute("COPY posts FROM 's3://mybucket/the/key/prefix' WITH CREDENTIALS aws_access_key_id=myaccesskey;aws_secret_access_key=mysecretaccesskey'    JSON AS 'auto';")
session.commit()
```

It doesn't matter whether I do the above or

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text 
session = get_redshift_session()
session.execute(text("COPY posts FROM 's3://mybucket/the/key/prefix' WITH CREDENTIALS aws_access_key_id=myaccesskey;aws_secret_access_key=mysecretaccesskey'    JSON AS 'auto';"))
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I basically had the same problem, though in my case it was more:

```
engine = create_engine('...')
engine.execute(text("COPY posts FROM 's3://mybucket/the/key/prefix' WITH CREDENTIALS aws_access_key_id=myaccesskey;aws_secret_access_key=mysecretaccesskey'    JSON AS 'auto';"))
```

By stepping through pdb, the problem was obviously the lack of a `.commit()` being invoked. I don't know why `session.commit()` is not working in your case (maybe the session "lost track" of the sent commands?) so it might not actually fix your problem.

Anyhow, as [explained in the sqlalchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit)

> Given this requirement, SQLAlchemy implements its own “autocommit” feature which works completely consistently across all backends. This is achieved by detecting statements which represent data-changing operations, i.e. INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE [...] If the statement is a text-only statement and the flag is not set, a regular expression is used to detect INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, as well as a variety of other commands for a particular backend.

So, there are 2 solutions, either:

- `text("COPY posts FROM 's3://mybucket/the/key/prefix' WITH CREDENTIALS aws_access_key_id=myaccesskey;aws_secret_access_key=mysecretaccesskey'    JSON AS 'auto';").execution_options(autocommit=True).`
- Or, get a fixed version of the redshift dialect... I just [opened a PR](https://github.com/sqlalchemy-redshift/sqlalchemy-redshift/pull/63) about it

Answer (score 7):

Add a commit to the end of the copy worked for me:

```
<your copy sql>;commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using the core expression language and `Connection.execute()` (as opposed to the ORM and sessions) to copy delimited files to Redshift with the code below.  Perhaps you could adapt it for JSON.

```
def copy_s3_to_redshift(conn, s3path, table, aws_access_key, aws_secret_key, delim='\t', uncompress='auto', ignoreheader=None):
    """Copy a TSV file from S3 into redshift.

    Note the CSV option is not used, so quotes and escapes are ignored.  Empty fields are loaded as null.
    Does not commit a transaction.
    :param Connection conn: SQLAlchemy Connection
    :param str uncompress: None, 'gzip', 'lzop', or 'auto' to autodetect from `s3path` extension.
    :param int ignoreheader: Ignore this many initial rows.
    :return: Whatever a copy command returns.
    """
    if uncompress == 'auto':
        uncompress = 'gzip' if s3path.endswith('.gz') else 'lzop' if s3path.endswith('.lzo') else None

    copy = text("""
        copy "{table}"
        from :s3path
        credentials 'aws_access_key_id={aws_access_key};aws_secret_access_key={aws_secret_key}'
        delimiter :delim
        emptyasnull
        ignoreheader :ignoreheader
        compupdate on
        comprows 1000000
        {uncompress};
        """.format(uncompress=uncompress or '', table=text(table), aws_access_key=aws_access_key, aws_secret_key=aws_secret_key))    # copy command doesn't like table name or keys single-quoted
    return conn.execute(copy, s3path=s3path, delim=delim, ignoreheader=ignoreheader or 0)
```