# I want to load data into an Amazon Redshift Cluster using python boto3 script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, boto3

I want to load data into an Amazon Redshift cluster using a boto3 Python script.

I want to create a script using boto3 python to do the following:

1. Create a cluster
2. Load data into the cluster
3. Create a report on the performance on the cluster

I see in boto3 there are no methods available to load the data into the cluster. Maybe from a flat-file or from S3.

How can I load the data into the cluster using boto3 or any other python package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Create an Amazon Redshift Cluster**

Call the [`create_cluster()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift.html#Redshift.Client.create_cluster) command.

**2. Load data into the cluster**

Amazon Redshift runs like a normal PostgreSQL v8.0.2 database. To run commands on the database itself (including the `COPY` command), you should establish a JDBC/ODBC connection to the database.

See: [Connecting to an Amazon Redshift Cluster Using SQL Client Tools - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-to-cluster.html)

A common method is to use `psycopg2`:

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("COPY...")
conn.commit()
```

See: [Copying data from S3 to AWS redshift using python and psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15650392/174777)

**3. Create a report on the performance on the cluster**

There are two sources of information for performance reporting:

- [Amazon Redshift Performance Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/metrics-listing.html) from Amazon CloudWatch
- The [STL Tables for Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_intro_STL_tables.html) in the database itself

See: [Monitoring Amazon Redshift Cluster Performance - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/metrics.html)

Comment: Excellent. Great answer and much appreciated. Thanks again.